# .ajax call creating 2 request packets only when hitting an IIS8 server - 2nd packet returns Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, iis, cross-domain

Ok, I’ve been delving into Fiddler a lot more to get to the bottom of this.. and it turns out 2 requests are being sent/received when I go to the IIS 8 site vs the IIS7 site. I have done the test using exactly the same client, and only changed the server address.. so EVERYTHING is the same except for the server address.

***Question: Why am I seeing 2 requests for IIS8 and how do I stop this?***

**When I send to the IIS 7 site – here is what I see – just one packet.** 
OPTIONS /SERVER/api/messagetypeopt/97 HTTP/1.1
Host: (.net 4 - IIS7 server)
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.33 Safari/535.11
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 13:31:04 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

**But when I go to the IIS 8 site I see to packets.!!  I’m only doing one ajax request though! 
Packet 1**
OPTIONS /server/api/messagetypeopt/115 HTTP/1.1
Host: .NET 4.5 IIS 8 server
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.33 Safari/535.11
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 13:26:30 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

**And packet 2 straight after packet 1**
PUT /server/api/messagetypeopt/115 HTTP/1.1
Host: .NET 4.5 IIS 8 server
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 84
Accept: */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.33 Safari/535.11
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: private
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 13:26:30 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5332

For completness i’ve added the javascript code doing the call.. this is done from a different domain to ther server(infact from my local PC)

```
var mesType = {
            MessageTypeID: mID,
            typeName: mType,
            OptIns:isChecked,
            SenderID: SENDER_ID,
            BranchID: CURRENT_BRANCH
        };

        try {
            JSON.stringify(mesType);
        }
        catch (ext) {
            alert("error on creating json object");
        }
// PUT THIS BACK IN!! to get optIns
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        $.ajax({
            url:  MYSERVERNAME + 'api/messagetypeopt/' + mID,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(mesType),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            jsonp: 'callback',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // WriteResponse(data);
                //alert('updated database for :' + mType + '=' + data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                if (inApp == 1)
                {
                alert('THere was an error updating the server' + x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            },
            complete: function (a, b) {
                //alert('complete:' + a + '\n' + b);
               $.mobile.loading('hide');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When a browser is asked to make a cross domain request with a method other than GET, HEAD, or POST the browser will first send an OPTIONS request with a Access-Control-Request-Method header for the method in question. The request with the method, in your case PUT, is only made if the server responds with a  Access-Control-Allow-Methods header that contains the desired method. Requests outside of GET, HEAD, or POST are termed "preflighted" requests. Mozilla has a fairly detailed writeup on the internals of CORS and more [specifics on preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests).

To answer your question, based on what you posted IIS7 does not appear to be setup to correctly handle Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and thus does not respond with the proper headers for the browser to continue with the request. IIS8 appears to be configured to handle CORS and responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Methods thus allowing the browser to continue with the actual PUT request. Changing the IIS8 configuration to not handle CORS requests should stop the second request. This can probably be accomplished by removing all custom headers defined in the application's web.config file that start with "Access-Control-Allow". If you want to only have one request and actually need the PUT request to get to the server I'd recommend serving the page making the request from the same domain to avoid CORS altogether.